# RubyInstaller Development Kit won't install :-(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Was wondering if you could please help me with my issue here?  I've
tried to install the Development Kit but when I type cd
 it comes out with a message stating
'The syntax of the command is incorrect'

p.s. I don't know if this is because the 'lib' file from my Rubygems
installation is said to be missing - ie. 'lib' file could not be
found.

Comment: Without you providing the *exact* output of the commands you've executed all we can do is guess what you have tried. Have you followed the wiki instructions? https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: Try to put it in a path without spaces, it gave me some problem with them. Also as Luis Lavena stated, we need more details.